# An error occurred while attempting to save the workbook in Tableau

Tags: extract, tableau-api, datasource

I am using Tableau desktop to create a workbook. When I am going to publish it to the tableau online server I am getting following error.

> > The tableau server you are publishing to does permit external database connections. Use the Data menu to create and extract for the
> >     following data sources.
>
> Data Extract Required
>
> "My data source name"

I have created a data source which get data from SQL on premises database.
Can anyone give me a solution for this.

Comment: From the question body, `Use the Data menu to create and [sic] extract for the following data sources.`

Comment: Why we can not publish live data sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box. Tableau Online only allows direct connections to specific [cloud data sources](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/to_connect_live_sql.htm).  If you want to refresh your extract to on-premises data sources, you'll want to leverage the [Tableau Bridge client](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/to_sync_local_data.htm)

Comment: I have installed it and still they are asking to extract the data source

Comment: Are you talking about Tableau Online or Tableau Public ?

Answer (score 2):

As the warning says, one needs to create an Extract.

> Though there are several options in your Tableau workflow for creating
> an extract, the primary method is described below.
>
> 1. After you connect to your data and set up the data source on the Data Source page, in the upper-right corner, select Extract, and then
>    click the Edit link to open the Extract Data dialog box.
>
> [image: Tableau Data Source Connection - Extract]
>
> 2. (Optional) Configure one or more of the following options to tell Tableau how to store, define filters for, and limit the amount of data.
> 3. When finished, click OK.
> 4. Click the sheet tab. Clicking the sheet tab initiates the creating of the extract.
> 5. In the subsequent dialog box, select a location to save the extract, give the extract file a name, and then click Save.

For more information on how to Extract Data, check [the official documentation](https://help.tableau.com/v2020.2/pro/desktop/en-us/extracting_data.htm).